# How to add tracking id for each request in fastify?

Tags: fastify, pinojs

Im using fastify as backend of my app. I also using pino logger.

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({
logger: true
})
```

I need that every time Im writing `fastify.log.info("something")` I need to see the log (in my terminal) with some trackingId. Like `{message: something, trackingId: 123}`. The tracking id should be the same throughout the request.

I tried to find how to do this in [fastify logger docs](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Logging/) and [pino logger](https://github.com/pinojs/pino) without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will produce the following output. Note that I'm using the `request.log` (NOT the `fastify.log`). In this way, the request id generated by fastify is printed out automatically.

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({
  logger: true,
  requestIdLogLabel: 'trackingId',
})

fastify.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
  request.log.info('Custom log message')
  return { hello: 'world' }
})
fastify.listen(8080)
```

Output:

```
{"level":30,"trackingId":"req-1","req":{"method":"GET","url":"/","hostname":"localhost:8080","remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":50743},"msg":"incoming request"}
{"level":30,"trackingId":"req-1","msg":"Custom log message"}
{"level":30,"trackingId":"req-1","res":{"statusCode":200},"responseTime":3.57566699385643,"msg":"request completed"}
```

The `req-id` is generated by Fastify. You can customize its value by implementing your own [`genReqId` function](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#genreqid).